# LINQ Generic GroupBy And SelectBy With Method Syntax

Tags: entity-framework, linq, select, group-by, linq-method-syntax

I'm trying to make it generic but didn't succeed. It doesnt get related User entity.

```
  return from transactions in context.Transaction
         where transactions.Date.Month == date.Month && transactions.Date.Year == date.Year
         join users in context.UserProfile on transactions.UserID equals users.UserID
         orderby transactions.MonthlyTotalExperiencePoint
         group transactions by transactions.UserID into groupedList
         select groupedList.First()).Take(50).ToList();
```

I've tried that:

```
public async Task<List<object>> GetAllGroup<TReturn, TOrderKey, TGroupKey>(Expression<Func<IGrouping<TGroupKey, TEntity>, TReturn>> selectExp,
                                                           Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereExp,
                                                           Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderKey>> orderbyExp,
                                                           bool descending,
                                                           int top,
                                                           Expression<Func<TEntity, TGroupKey>> groupByExp,
                                                           params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeExps)
    {
        var query = DbSet.Where(whereExp);
        query = !descending ? query.OrderBy(orderbyExp) : query.OrderByDescending(orderbyExp);
        if (includeExps != null)
            query = includeExps.Aggregate(query, (current, exp) => current.Include(exp));
        return await query.GroupBy(groupByExp).Select(selectExp).Take(top).ToListAsync();
    }
```

It gives error at usage:

```
 var item = await transactionRepository.GetAllGroup(x => x.FirstOrDefault(), x => x.Date != null, x => x.MonthlyTotalExperiencePoint, true, 50, x => x.MonthlyTotalExperiencePoint, x => x.User);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "generic"?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten an independent parameterized method

Comment: It's still not clear. Please clarify further and it would be good if you add some code that would show how to you wish to use this method

Comment: @OfirWinegarten code edited :)

Comment: This code won't compile ofcourse. You shoud send in the `TEntity` parameter and use it instead of `DbSet.`

Comment: Does it compile? what error does it give?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten i changed code now it doesnt get related User entity.

Comment: It was because of lazyloading, sorry for confusing. Thank you, it worked now.